# Does order of operation and registration matter on selectable channel?

Tags: java, nio

I couldn't clearly understand this from java documentation.

Consider I have a selectable channel (`SocketChannel`), in non-blocking mode.

If I call `channel.connect()`, and it returns false, and I then register the channel with a selector, would `select()` ever update the created key with "connect" operation, if the connection was actually finished before the select() was first invoked, or even before the registration was done?

The order of events would be:

- `connect` (returns `false`)
- somehow socket becomes "connected" at this time
- `register` (returns selection key)
- `select` (done on a different thread, but guaranteed after `register`)

This applies to other operations as well. In general, does it matter when the channel is registered in relation to the last operation done on that channel, or would selection key receive all the outstanding events that happened since last channel operation anyway?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc for [SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html):

> Socket channels support non-blocking connection: A socket channel may
>   be created and the process of establishing the link to the remote
>   socket may be initiated via the connect method for later completion by
>   the finishConnect method. Whether or not a connection operation is in
>   progress may be determined by invoking the isConnectionPending method.

Additionally, the doc for [SocketChannel.connect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) states:

> If the connection is established immediately, as can happen with a
>   local connection, then this method returns true. Otherwise this method
>   returns false and the connection operation must later be completed by
>   invoking the finishConnect method

So the sequence of events should be:

- channel.connect() - returns false
- channel.register()
- selector.select()
- when the channel is selected, call channel.finishConnect()
- if finishConnect() returns true, deregister the channel for OP_CONNECT

So yes, the selector will make sure that the selection for this socket channel is placed in its ready set for OP_CONNECT

Comment: I'm sorry, but where in the quoted docs it's apparent that an event will be selected if it happened prior to the registration?

Comment: @PawelVeselov Good question, but the answer to your original question is 'yes': the `OP_CONNECT` even will fire every time you `select()` after connection has completed, until you deregister `OP_CONNECT.`

Comment: @EJP I thought that was my original question, or at least - where does it say that it is guaranteed that the selection key will state that the connection operation is pending, even if happened before the registration of the the channel? You say it will, but I don't see why.

Comment: I refer to your original question, not your comment above. The answer to your comment is implicit if not explicit in the definition of OP_CONNECT.